# Cypress not updating database during test

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress

I have a react/laravel ecommerce app that allows users to register, login, add products to a cart, and delete a cart (which creates a new empty one tied to same user in the background). If I run the app in localhost or on vercel, I can increment the quantity of an item in the cart. For example, when I add a "coffee mug" for the first time from the products page, quantity in cart will show as 1. If I go back to the products page and click ADD on "coffee mug" again, quantity in cart will have incremented up by 1 and display as 2.

In the database, there is a cart object tied to a user. There are also cartItem objects tied to a given cart, and each cartItem has a cartId, productId, and quantity.

CYPRESS
When I try to mimic these steps in Cypress, I am able to login a user and add a single item with quantity of 1 to the cart. My final test in Cypress can navigate to the cart page after adding "coffee mug" to cart, and can see coffee mug (quantity of 1) in the cart. HOWEVER, if I run the test block a second time, the quantity of the "coffee mug" item in the cart **does not increment up by 1 as expected**.

Here is my cypress code:
cypress/e2e/cart.cy.js --

```js
describe('tests layout and functionality of cart page', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.log("cart.cy.js before each running...")

    // login user
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/login")
    cy.get("[data-testid='login-email-field']").type("batman00@gmail.com")
    cy.get("[data-testid='login-password-field']").type("Green@55")
    cy.get("[data-testid='login-submit-button']").click() 
    
    // add item to cart 
    cy.get("[data-testid='all-products-link']").click()
  
    // this item is the coffee mug 
    cy.get("[data-testid='add-product-button']").eq(1).click() 

    // WHY ISN'T THIS INCREMENTING EACH TIME? 
    // I CAN INCREMENT IT IF I JUST OPEN IN LOCALHOST, BUT NOT HERE FROM CYPRESS 

    // logout 
    cy.get("[data-testid='logout-button']").click()
  })


  it('shows the current cart for a logged-in user', () => {
     // login user
     cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/login")
     cy.get("[data-testid='login-email-field']").type("batman00@gmail.com")
     cy.get("[data-testid='login-password-field']").type("Green@55")
     cy.get("[data-testid='login-submit-button']").click() 
 
     // click cart link 
     cy.get("[data-testid='cart-link']").click()
 
  })

})
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Is the cart cleared on login/logout? Cypress maintains clean state between tests by default, so it is meant to be as if a user is logging in for the first time.

Comment: the cart items/cart in the database are not cleared on login/logout. Here is a link to the repo -- https://github.com/dlindqu3/store2-frontend

Comment: For this test, I assume that there is already a user with a cart. Within Cypress, I just want to login with that user, then increment up the quantity of the item in the cart each time I run the test, but this does not work.

Comment: for instance, the user batman00 already exists in the database and has a cart.